How to interact with an html button element while a dialog element is open
I have a web page with html dialog element and there is a button on the page, how to enable interacting on the page elements while the dialog element is open. Example:


document.getElementById("myDialog")?.showModal();
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dialog Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <dialog id="myDialog">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum
        corporis, fugit ullam accusantium porro quasi.
      </p>
    </dialog>

    <button onclick="alert('button clicked')">Click</button>
  </body>
</html>




https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal: "The showModal() method of the HTMLDialogElement interface displays the dialog as a modal, over the top of any other dialogs that might be present. It displays in the top layer, along with a ::backdrop pseudo-element. Interaction outside the dialog is blocked and the content outside it is rendered inert."

If you do not want that, then you want the show method instead: "The show() method of the HTMLDialogElement interface displays the dialog modelessly, i.e. still allowing interaction with content outside of the dialog."

I'm making a chrome extension where a button added to the content script (the web pages) and should take a screen when I click on it, and I cannot change the called method on the dialog element, so somehow want the button not to be inert.
